# can i determine a similar triangle using side side angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I know that to determine "similar triangles", all the information we need is either

1) angle angle

2) side side side

3) side angle side

But I was just wondering, is it possible to determine "similar triangles" based on "side side angle", i.e. the angle is not in between the two sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a picture taken from [the law of sines wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#The_ambiguous_case_of_triangle_solution):

[image]

Here side lengths a and c are known, as well as the angle at corner A.
There are two possibilities for the triangle: The angle between a and c can be either acute or obtuse. If you know which, and it is the same for the two side-side-angle triangles you are comparing, then you can conclude that the triangles are similar.

Answer (score 1):

No. Two similar triangles should always have the same angles. However, given two sides and an angle not in between these two, you can easily construct triangles with different angles.
Assume the given angle is $\alpha$ and you have the sides $a,b$. Just pick any angle $\beta$ such that $\alpha + \beta < 180^{\circ}$ and draw a triangle that has $\beta$ as angle between $a$ and $b$. You will notice that this will always work, so you can construct different, non-similar triangles given side,side,angle.

Comment: Not every $\beta$ works for a particular $\alpha$. Generally there are only two values that work, one acute and one obtuse. We know the sine of third angle from the sine rule, but there are two possibilities for the angle itself, leading to two possibilities for $\beta$ (or just one if the third angle happens to be right angle).